# Python dictionary only keeps information from last iteration of loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to create a loop to populate a **dictionary within a dictionary** from a **Series**:
The expected result is:

```
{1: {'KEY Mult. by 10': 10, 'KEY Add by 10': 11},
 2: {'KEY Mult. by 10': 20, 'KEY Add by 10': 12},
 3: {'KEY Mult. by 10': 30, 'KEY Add by 10': 13},
 4: {'KEY Mult. by 10': 40, 'KEY Add by 10': 14},
 5: {'KEY Mult. by 10': 50, 'KEY Add by 10': 15}}
```

what I'm doing is:

```
series_1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])

first_dict = dict()                         # creating first level of Dict 
second_dict = dict({'KEY Mult. by 10': 0,   # creating second level of Dict
                   'KEY Add by 10': 0})

for i in series_1:
       
    first_dict[i] = second_dict
 
    first_dict[i]['KEY Mult. by 10'] = i *10
    first_dict[i]['KEY Add by 10'] = i + 10
```

The result from the above ends up being:

```
{1: {'KEY Mult. by 10': 50, 'KEY Add by 10': 15},
 2: {'KEY Mult. by 10': 50, 'KEY Add by 10': 15},
 3: {'KEY Mult. by 10': 50, 'KEY Add by 10': 15},
 4: {'KEY Mult. by 10': 50, 'KEY Add by 10': 15},
 5: {'KEY Mult. by 10': 50, 'KEY Add by 10': 15}}
```

Then, when I try to change value for one of the keys, it changes for all of them:

```
first_dict[3]['KEY Mult. by 10'] = 20

print(first_dict)

{1: {'KEY Mult. by 10': 20, 'KEY Add by 10': 15},
 2: {'KEY Mult. by 10': 20, 'KEY Add by 10': 15},
 3: {'KEY Mult. by 10': 20, 'KEY Add by 10': 15},
 4: {'KEY Mult. by 10': 20, 'KEY Add by 10': 15},
 5: {'KEY Mult. by 10': 20, 'KEY Add by 10': 15}}
```

Can any one help me please?

Comment: @LucasRoberts you can see the expected result at the begging of the question

Comment: Yep I see it now.

Comment: Looks like you made a shallow copy of the dictionary in the loop.

Comment: You only have a single `second_dict`. You alter it over and over in the loop. Try creating the dict inside the loop instead. Then you'll have independent dicts. Alternatively use a dict comprehension: `second_dict = {i: {'KEY Mult. by 10': i *10, 'KEY Add by 10': i+10} for i in series_1}`

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you very much for the comments... it was really helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the comments describe the solution but I'll elaborate some.

The dictionary is the same block of memory in each of the outer indices.
To see this after you run:

```
for i in series_1:
    first_dict[i] = second_dict
```

look at the `id()` of two of the inner dictionaries, these are the memory locations:

```
id(first_dict[1]) # 4511987904
id(first_dict[2])
```

With the way the code is currently written any write to ***any*** of the dictionaries will overwrite all of them.
On your machine you will have a (a single one) different value for the ids but it is the same idea-they will be all the same memory location.

To fix this you can call the constructor ***inside*** the for loop and it will allocate new memory ***for each*** inner dictionary.

```
for i in series_1:
    first_dict[i] = dict({'KEY Mult. by 10': 0,'KEY Add by 10': 0})
    first_dict[i]['KEY Mult. by 10'] = i * 10
    first_dict[i]['KEY Add by 10'] = i + 10
```

then you will see different `id()` return values for each inner dictionary and you can confirm they are different memory locations with `id()`:

```
>>> id(first_dict[3])
4511988352
>>> id(first_dict[1])
4511988160
```

again, on your machine these will be different `id()` values but the idea is the same, you are making space for each inner dictionary separately.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!... looking at **omercotkd's** comment, I believe the below change would be the best.. right?

first_dict[i] = dict({'KEY Mult. by 10': 0,'KEY Add by 10': 0})

first_dict[i] = dict()

because then the code will create the 2 keys inside each of the dictionaries :D

thank you again!!

Comment: @JeffersonRobinski YMMV. The distinction of best here is most likely your preference. I'm not sure how large the data are or how much updating you'd need to perform in your actual implementation. If you have many candidate multiply or add values then doing all of them-if possible-and then doing a single `dict.update()` might make more sense. Outside of the scenario I just mentioned, I'd probably use the constructor example I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

Change `first_dict[i] = second_dict` to: `first_dict[i] = dict()` and it will work as expacted, by doing so you can also remove the creation of the "second level of Dict"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that u use the same dictionary multiple times, you have to use a copy oh the `second_dict`

```
import pandas as pd

series_1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

first_dict = dict()  # creating first level of Dict
second_dict = dict({'KEY Mult. by 10': 0,  # creating second level of Dict
                    'KEY Add by 10': 0})

for i in series_1:
    first_dict[i] = second_dict.copy()

    first_dict[i]['KEY Mult. by 10'] = i * 10
    first_dict[i]['KEY Add by 10'] = i + 10
```